# Expecting top level declaration error on top level declaration

Tags: kotlin

I'm new to Kotlin, and, man, it's awesome!

I'm creating a Discord bot with it using JDA & Maven, it works, but, I created a basic command handler, and now, I get a lot of errors saying "Expecting top level declaration" on a top level declaration.

Here is my code (btw, I already found that `Array<String?>` error):

```
package com.blueslimee.kirani.listeners

import net.dv8tion.jda.core.entities.*
import net.dv8tion.jda.core.hooks.*
import net.dv8tion.jda.core.JDA
import net.dv8tion.jda.core.events.message.MessageReceivedEvent
import com.blueslimee.kirani.utils.KiraniLogging
import com.blueslimee.kirani.KiraniCommand
import com.blueslimee.kirani.utils.Registry

class MessageListener() : ListenerAdapter() {
  override fun onMessageReceived (event: MessageReceivedEvent) {
    val jda: JDA = event.getJDA()
    // todo: cmds guild-only  event.isFromType(ChannelType.TEXT)
    if (!event.getAuthor().isBot()) {
        var msgContent: String? = event.getMessage()
        if (msgContent === null) {
          return 
        }
        var args: Array<String?> = msgContent!!.split(" ")
        var firstArg: String? = args[0]
        if (!firstArg!!.startsWith("k-", true)) {
          return 
        }
        firstArg = firstArg!!.replace("k-", "", true)
        var cmde: KiraniCommand? = Registry.getCommand(firstArg)
        if (cmde  != null) {
          try {
            cmde!!.run(jda, event, args)
          } catch (e: Exception) {
            event.getChannel().sendMessage("Oopsie Woopsie, um erro ocorreu! Meu dono já foi reportado sobre, peço que aguarde.").queue()
            e.printStackTrace()
          }
       }
    }
  }
}
```

Thanks!

Comment: Please edit your question to include your source code as part of it, not as an external link. Also, please point to a specific line where you get an error.

Comment: @yole the code is big, sooo 

Answer (score 0):

Use

```
var args: List<String> = msgContent.split(" ").toList()
```

instead of

```
var args: Array<String?> = msgContent!!.split(" ")
```

Comment: The message content can be null if there is no content (only a embed), and its possible call a function on a possibly-null var without using safe call or using `!!`? @sasikumar